# Using Instagram Graph API to pull information on creators/public account

Tags: node.js, reactjs, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I'm a little bit confused about how to use the Instagram Graph API. Do I need a business/creator account as well as register my app to be approved by Facebook to use the API itself? Any other requirements? My goal for the app is to be able to enter in someone's Instagram handle and able to get back some information such as name, id, profile picture, followers, as well as metrics such as engagement rate and average likes. Is that possible without needing to be approved to use it by Facebook? Is there an easy way to get that information?